# getting exception when try to use vector Drawables in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

My Code is Working Fine but whenever I try to add the vectordrables in my app I got the exception.

I am Using RecyclerView to Show the item list.

[https://i.imgur.com/GRuWMe5.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F0np.png)

My xml item layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/note_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sample Text"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/fab_edit_note"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_edit_note"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

if I run the app with vector drawables I got an exception and when remove the it from FloatingActionButton.
My App works fine... I need Solution Help me to figure out...

I Also Added the Following Line in the App Module File but it didn't work...

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

Here is Android Studio LogCat.

```
06-10 12:44:45.920 3137-3137/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-10 12:44:46.150 3137-3137/com.codemsi.notes W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-10 12:44:46.170 3137-3137/com.codemsi.notes E/Process: android_os_Process_getProcessNameByPid pid is 3137
06-10 12:44:46.170 3137-3137/com.codemsi.notes E/Process: android_os_Process_getProcessNameByPid value is m.codemsi.notes
06-10 12:44:46.190 3137-3137/com.codemsi.notes I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
06-10 12:44:46.190 3137-3137/com.codemsi.notes I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
06-10 12:44:46.460 3137-3164/com.codemsi.notes D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
06-10 12:44:46.470 3137-3137/com.codemsi.notes D/Atlas: Validating map...
06-10 12:44:46.530 3137-3164/com.codemsi.notes I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3.C8.05.01.00.115.128_msm8916_64_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3.C8.05.01.00.115.128__release_AU (I55c48cad9a)
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04
    Build Date: 03/21/17 Tue
    Local Branch: 
    Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3.C8.05.01.00.115.128
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
06-10 12:44:46.540 3137-3164/com.codemsi.notes I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-10 12:44:46.550 3137-3164/com.codemsi.notes D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
06-10 12:44:46.570 3137-3137/com.codemsi.notes W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f070072 (t=6 e=114) (error -75)
06-10 12:44:46.580 3137-3137/com.codemsi.notes D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-10 12:44:46.590 3137-3137/com.codemsi.notes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.codemsi.notes, PID: 3137
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at com.codemsi.notes.model.NotesAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NotesAdapter.java:31)
        at com.codemsi.notes.model.NotesAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NotesAdapter.java:17)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15697)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5064)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15697)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5064)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:148)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:43)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1892)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:918)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15697)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5064)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15697)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5064)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15697)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5064)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15697)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5064)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15697)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5064)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15697)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5064)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2260)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2010)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$
06-10 12:44:46.680 3137-3137/com.codemsi.notes I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3137 SIG: 9
06-10 12:44:46.680 3137-3137/com.codemsi.notes V/Process: killProcess [3137] Callers=com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:99 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690 <bottom of call stack>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  app:src="@drawable/ic_edit" instead and check it out if it works

Answer (score 0):

Use app:srcCompat = "@drawable/ic_edit" instead of android:src

Answer (score 0):

Use app:srcCompat to reference vector drawable

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_edit_note"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```